# Suggestions for improving my Tic-Tac-Toe code in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, game

I have some hack-ey programming experience and recently made a Tic-Tac-Toe game in JavaScript. The game seems to work fine. I am looking for some constructive criticism to help understand what can be better.

(full code in [Github repo](https://github.com/erdogan/Tic-Tac-Toe))

```
function Player(name, selector, color) {
    this.name = name || "";
    this.moves = [];
    this.chances = [];
    this.selector = selector || "x";
    this.color = color;
}

// Setup
window.players = [];
var user = new Player('user', 'O', 'green');
var computer = new Player('computer', 'X', 'pink');
players.push(user);
players.push(computer);

// Trackers for the board and moves
var board = ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'A3', 'B3', 'C3'];
var wins = ['A1A2A3', 'B1B2B3', 'C1C2C3', 'A1B1C1', 'A2B2C2', 'A3B3C3', 'A1B2C3', 'C1B2A3'];
var moves = 1;
var currentPlayer = players[0];
var game = 1;

// Handle clicks
$(".box").click(function (event) {
    if (getCurrentPlayer() === user && game == 1) usersMove(event.target.id);
});

// *** MOVES *** 
// With every move, these functions update the state of the board

function usersMove(boxId) {
    if (validMove(boxId) === true) {
        makeMove(user, boxId);
    } else alert('taken');
}

function computersMove() {
    makeMove(computer, getBestNextMove(computer));
}

function validMove(boxId) {
    return (board.indexOf(boxId) != -1);
}

function markBox(player, boxId) {
    $("#" + boxId).text(player.selector).addClass(player.color);
}

function updateBoard(boxId) {
    board.splice(board.indexOf(boxId), 1);
}

function updateMoves(player, boxId) {
    moves = moves + 1;
    player.moves.push(boxId);
}

function makeMove(player, boxId) {
    if (moves < 10) {
        markBox(player, boxId);
        updateBoard(boxId);
        updateMoves(player, boxId);
        addChances(player, boxId);
        removeChances(getOtherPlayer(), boxId);
        if (checkWin(getCurrentPlayer(), boxId) === false) {         
            getBestNextMove(player);
            setTimeout(function () { nextTurn() }, 500);
        }
    } else endGame("Nobody");
}

// *** TRACK AND UPDATE USER'S CHANCES *** 

// Add to current player chances array
function addChances(player, boxId) {
    for (var i = 0; i < wins.length; i++) {
        if (wins[i].indexOf(boxId) !== -1 && player.chances.indexOf(wins[i]) === -1 && getOtherPlayer().chances.indexOf(wins[i]) === -1) {
            player.chances.push(wins[i]);
            wins.splice(wins.indexOf(wins[i]), 1);
            i--;
        }
    }
}

// Eliminate arrays from other player chances array
function removeChances(player, boxId) { 
    for (var i = 0; i < player.chances.length; i++) {
        if (player.chances[i].indexOf(boxId) !== -1) {
            player.chances.splice(player.chances.indexOf(player.chances[i]), 1);
            i--;
        }
    }
}

// *** FIND THE BEST NEXT MOVE *** 

function getBestNextMove(player) {
    var c = player.chances;
    var m = player.moves;
    for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < m.length; j++) {
            if (c[i].indexOf(m[j]) != -1) {
                c[i] = c[i].replace(m[j], "");
            }
        }
    }
    if (c.length > 0 && c[0].length == 2) { 
        return c[0];
    } else return sortMoves();
}

function sortMoves(){
    var scores = [];
    var bestMoves = [];

    // rank moves based on score
    for (var i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        scores.push({ 'boxId' : board[i], 'val' : rankMove(board[i]) });
    }
    scores.sort(function(a,b) {
        return b.val - a.val;
    });

    // get all options with the highest score
    for (var i = 0; i< scores.length; i++) {
        if (scores[i].val == scores[0].val) {
            bestMoves.push(scores[i]['boxId']);
        }
    }

    // select a random one from the highest score options
    var moveIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*bestMoves.length);
    return scores[moveIndex].boxId;
}

function rankMove(boxId) {
    var score = 0;
    for (var p = 0; p < players.length; p++) {
        var c = players[p].chances;
        for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
            if (c[i].indexOf(boxId) !== -1) {
                score += 1;
                // if user is one step away from winning, increase chances
                if (c[i].length == 2) score += 5;
            }
        }
    }
    return score;
}

function sortByLength(arr) {
    arr.sort(function(a, b){
      return a.length - b.length;
    });    
    return arr;
}

// *** SETTERS & GETTERS

function getCurrentPlayer() {
    return currentPlayer;
}

function setCurrentPlayer(player) {
    currentPlayer = player;
    return currentPlayer;
}

function getOtherPlayer() {
    if (getCurrentPlayer() == players[0]) {
        return players[1];
    } else return players[0];
}

function nextTurn() {
        if (getCurrentPlayer() === players[0]) {
            setCurrentPlayer(players[1]);
            computersMove();
        } else setCurrentPlayer(players[0]);
}

// *** CHECK FOR WINNERS, CONTINUE/END

function checkWin(player, boxId) {
    var c = player.chances;
    for (var i = 0, tot = c.length; i < tot; i++) {
        if (c[i].length == 2 & c[i] == boxId ) {
            endGame(player);
            return true;
        }
    }
    if (board.length == 0 && game == 1) {
        endGame();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function endGame(winner) {
    game = 0;
    if (winner) {
        alert(winner.name + " wins!");
    } else alert("it's a draw!");
}
```

Comment: I think you should try a search tree with Alpha Beta pruning Here's the wikipedia link to the algorithm
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning

Comment: Additionally, alpha-beta pruning is a bit overkill for Tic-Tac-Toe, don't you think?

Comment: And he doesn't even use minimax. Sorry if it seems rude - this shouldn't discourage you from participating further to our community. Have a good day!

Comment: @Romantic Electron: Thanks for the pointer, will look into it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is nice, most comments are minor issues. General issues are:

1. the way you're involving winning conditions with the chance system
2. user interaction: you're over-using alerts when you could slide down messages with jQuery. Avoid modal interfaces.
3. AI is simple, but that may be what you want.

Line-by-line review:

```
function Player(name, selector, color) {
    this.name = name || "";
    this.moves = [];
    this.chances = [];
    this.selector = selector || "x";
    this.color = color;
}
```

I don't think silently choosing defaults for `selector` and `name` helps.

```
// Setup
window.players = [];
var user = new Player('user', 'O', 'green');
var computer = new Player('computer', 'X', 'pink');
players.push(user);
players.push(computer);
```

Thrive for concise code: `window.players = [user, computer];`

```
// Trackers for the board and moves
var board = ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'A3', 'B3', 'C3'];
var wins = ['A1A2A3', 'B1B2B3', 'C1C2C3', 'A1B1C1', 'A2B2C2', 'A3B3C3', 'A1B2C3', 'C1B2A3'];
var moves = 1;
var currentPlayer = players[0];
var game = 1;
```

The `game` name is unclear, and should be a boolean.

```
// Handle clicks
$(".box").click(function (event) {
    if (getCurrentPlayer() === user && game == 1) usersMove(event.target.id);
});
```

Silently rejecting click is probably not too intuitive for the user ("where has my click gone?"), but I assume this never occurs in practice since the AI plays instantly.

```
// *** MOVES *** 
// With every move, these functions update the state of the board

function usersMove(boxId) {
    if (validMove(boxId) === true) {
        makeMove(user, boxId);
    } else alert('taken');
}
```

Good, you're informing the user. However, `alert()` is a bit rude.

```
function computersMove() {
    makeMove(computer, getBestNextMove(computer));
}

function validMove(boxId) {
    return (board.indexOf(boxId) != -1);
}

function markBox(player, boxId) {
    $("#" + boxId).text(player.selector).addClass(player.color);
}

function updateBoard(boxId) {
    board.splice(board.indexOf(boxId), 1);
}

function updateMoves(player, boxId) {
    moves = moves + 1;
    player.moves.push(boxId);
}

function makeMove(player, boxId) {
    if (moves < 10) {
        markBox(player, boxId);
        updateBoard(boxId);
        updateMoves(player, boxId);
        addChances(player, boxId);
        removeChances(getOtherPlayer(), boxId);
```

I don't find this too readable. Isn't it simpler to put everything into `makeMove` with comments like `// mark chosen box`?

```
        if (checkWin(getCurrentPlayer(), boxId) === false) {         
            getBestNextMove(player);
            setTimeout(function () { nextTurn() }, 500);
        }
    } else endGame("Nobody");
}

// *** TRACK AND UPDATE USER'S CHANCES ***
```

At this point, even when quickly looking at occurrences of "chance" in the rest of code the code, I have no idea what `chances` are. This deserves a better comment.

```
// Add to current player chances array
function addChances(player, boxId) {
    for (var i = 0; i < wins.length; i++) {
        if (wins[i].indexOf(boxId) !== -1 && player.chances.indexOf(wins[i]) === -1 && getOtherPlayer().chances.indexOf(wins[i]) === -1) {
```

Consider splitting this line so that it fits in ~80 chars. How could `wins[i].indexOf(boxId)` be -1?

```
            player.chances.push(wins[i]);
            wins.splice(wins.indexOf(wins[i]), 1);
            i--;
```

Okay.. got it. Iit looks like that when part of a winning move is done by a player, we add it to the player possible winning moves. Isn't this over-engineered? Why don't you simply check on every move if a winning move as made? You don't need to store wins or chances, just check 8 configurations. (Such a function would also work for larger grids, by the way.)

```
        }
    }
}

// Eliminate arrays from other player chances array
function removeChances(player, boxId) { 
    for (var i = 0; i < player.chances.length; i++) {
        if (player.chances[i].indexOf(boxId) !== -1) {
            player.chances.splice(player.chances.indexOf(player.chances[i]), 1);
            i--;
        }
    }
}

// *** FIND THE BEST NEXT MOVE *** 

function getBestNextMove(player) {
    var c = player.chances;
    var m = player.moves;
    for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < m.length; j++) {
            if (c[i].indexOf(m[j]) != -1) {
                c[i] = c[i].replace(m[j], "");
            }
```

This is quite confusing, why don't you do this when adding chances? (If I understood correctly, you're removing already done moves from chances.)

```
        }
    }
    if (c.length > 0 && c[0].length == 2) { 
        return c[0];
    } else return sortMoves();
```

(Personal state: I don't really like this pattern where you have braces in the first branch but not in the second.)

```
}

function sortMoves(){
    var scores = [];
    var bestMoves = [];

    // rank moves based on score
    for (var i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        scores.push({ 'boxId' : board[i], 'val' : rankMove(board[i]) });
    }
    scores.sort(function(a,b) {
        return b.val - a.val;
    });

    // get all options with the highest score
    for (var i = 0; i< scores.length; i++) {
        if (scores[i].val == scores[0].val) {
            bestMoves.push(scores[i]['boxId']);
        }
    }

    // select a random one from the highest score options
    var moveIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*bestMoves.length);
    return scores[moveIndex].boxId;
```

Learn to use JavaScript collection functions. `reduce()` can get you the max, and `filter()` can get you all maxs.

```
}

function rankMove(boxId) {
    var score = 0;
    for (var p = 0; p < players.length; p++) {
        var c = players[p].chances;
        for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
            if (c[i].indexOf(boxId) !== -1) {
                score += 1;
                // if user is one step away from winning, increase chances
                if (c[i].length == 2) score += 5;
            }
        }
    }
    return score;
}
```

You might want to use minimax if you want your AI not to make any mistakes. However, it can be more frustrating to play.

```
function sortByLength(arr) {
    arr.sort(function(a, b){
      return a.length - b.length;
    });    
    return arr;
}
```

Unused.

```
// *** SETTERS & GETTERS

function getCurrentPlayer() {
    return currentPlayer;
}
```

Seriously?

```
function getOtherPlayer() {
    if (getCurrentPlayer() == players[0]) {
        return players[1];
    } else return players[0];
}
```

See, the pattern mentioned above makes it seem like there's a difference between the two branchs, but they're really symmetrical.

```
function nextTurn() {
        if (getCurrentPlayer() === players[0]) {
            setCurrentPlayer(players[1]);
            computersMove();
        } else setCurrentPlayer(players[0]);
}
```

Check your indentation.

```
    if (board.length == 0 && game == 1) {
        endGame();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Feels quite wrong... but you can't do much about it since endGame() won't return before user has clicked on the pop-up.

```
function endGame(winner) {
    game = 0;
    if (winner) {
        alert(winner.name + " wins!");
    } else alert("it's a draw!");
}
```

If the alert() was not intrusive, you could write endGame() as:

```
function gameEnded(winner) {
    gameIsEnded = board.length == 0 && game == 1;
    if (gameIsEnded) {
        warnUser(winner.name + " wins!");
    } else {
        warnUser("It's a draw!");
    }

    return gameIsEnded;
}
```

Then, in `nextTurn()`, you could simply `return gameEnded()`. When you see `return true;`/`return false;`, there's usually something to improve.

Comment: this is immensely helpful, I appreciate your detailed feedback, there are some great learnings for me here! To clarify two points that I did not quite understand: (1) What's wrong with the getCurrentPlayer function? Isn't it standard practice to use getters for game-wide variables? (2) Also, you said endGame function feels quite wrong: how would it be better? Again, thank you so much for taking the time to review my code.

Comment: Getters are taught at school, but are not really useful here, right? They can add value when they hide some logic, as in `getOtherPlayer`. I'll propose a better `endGame` at the end of my answer.

Comment: Very helpful, great points. I like the rule of thumb for non-descript returns. Thank you so much!